# Chutzpah {Transforms Setting} :-.Net Framework Implementation

Tags: angularjs, chutzpah, lcov

I am trying to get my angular + JS Coverage report in LCov Format.So tried to implement it as below:-

```
{
  "CodeCoverageExcludes":  
    [
                
                "*/Tests/**/*.js",
                "*/Web/App_Themes/test*.js",
                "*/Web/App_Themes/brands/*.js",
                "*/Web/App_Themes/basictest/js/*.js",
                "*/Web/App_Themes/Intranet/*.js"                       
          
    ],  

    "Transforms": [
             { "Name": "lcov", "Path": "lcov.dat" }
    ]

}
```

This above file is called as chutzpah.json. It's not giving me the correct overage report.Please suggest how and where to implement it to get the correct  coverage report

Comment: Is this Angular 1 or 2?

Comment: it's 1.........

Comment: Could you link to a full repro (maybe a github repo?)